# Facebook link maker

Tags: facebook

How do I add a facebook link to my page so that people can "like" it?

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the like box code from here:

http://developers.facebook.com/plugins

Follow the steps to get the code and then put on your website.